# meteor build on remote server ... public packages not loading?

Tags: git, meteor

I'm trying to work on a deployment script to get a local meteor git repository to bundle on a remote ec2 instance.

Meteor version 1.0.3.1

everything is fine until i run

`meteor build --directory /home/foouser/foouser`

and then i get

```
=> Errors while initializing project:         

While selecting package versions:
error: unknown package: accounting
```

and this continues for each non-local package in the app...

in the old days we could call "mrt build" and it would load the packages for us from smart.json, what is the right way to do this now ?

many thanks in advance !

.meteor/packages looks like this

```
standard-app-packages
accounts-ui
less
accounts-password
npm-container
reactive-var

matb33:collection-hooks
iron:router
nemo64:bootstrap
meteorhacks:npm
alanning:roles
mrt:underscore-string-latest
lepozepo:accounting

myprivatepackage
myprivpackage2
```

Comment: What does you `.meteor/packages` file look like? What version of meteor are you using?

Comment: Version 1.0.3 (latest), .meteor/packages is just that generated by default : first a list of cdg packages (standard-app-packages, accounts-ui, etc), then external packages (lepozepo:accounting, matb33:collection-hooks, etc), then internal packages... the build works fine on my local machine, but on ec2 ubuntu 12.04 it throws the errors